# Why do German and US Layout only differ by Y and Z?

Tags: keyboard-layout

The US and German character layouts only differ by the Y and Z characters, those are exchanged. There is the subtlety that the US character layout usually comes with an ANSI button layout (slim enter) whereas the German character layout is usually with the ISO button layout (large enter).

While looking for the history of this, one often finds that the relative frequency of characters is different in German and English. The letters on the typewriter become entangled when used too fast, therefore one needs to space frequently used characters apart. This is okay, I do see this difference in relative frequency of the characters “Y” and “Z”.

However, why did they stop there? Why did they only change two characters and not design a completely different (like DVORAK) layout for German (assuming English was first)? I am often in the situation where the two keyboard layouts are similar enough that my fingers can type really fast but now catch on the Y–Z thing fast enough. If the layout was completely different, I might have an easier time to switch between the layouts if needed.

So why do they only differ by exactly one permutation of the letters and nothing more (neglecting special characters)?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the actual frequency analysis of German language the QWERTZ layout is still crap . So there must be other reasons to why they did not change the layout too much after the constraints of the mechanics where gone.

I am pretty confident it has to do whit user adoption. I switched to Neo2 lately and it was a pain at the start (see below). So all the typists that switch from mechanical typewriter to computer keyboard would have to learn a new layout and would loose their ability to be productive on a typewriter in addition their productivity on the computer would be very low at the start. So they stuck with the old typewriter layout. And the same problem persist until today. I have to carry with me a thumbdrive (which I do anyway) that allows me to inject key remaping into windows machines, otherwise I am screwed when using one (Linux supports alternate layouts very well).

On a side note: If you wan one that actually does the job right for German and is pretty decent too for other European languaes have a look at he [Neo2](http://neo-layout.org/) layout. I especially like how they handle all the special chareters, really useful for programming.

Comment: I use the US layout myself as I mostly type English anyway (physics, programming). Still I wonder why the German and English typewriter were designed so similarly? Were there a lot of people going back and forth between two typewriters?

Comment: hmm I don't think so. And I don't know much about typewriter mechanics, so I can't  say much else about it, than that were problems with bi-/trigrams and hammers clogging up. Also know that frequency analysis of language is older than the typewriter, since Morse already used it. So big question for me too.